# Django Python - Variable seems to be getting cached?

Tags: python, django, caching

Within my Django app I obtain a list of projects within our Google Cloud Organisation with the following:

```
try:
    global projectdicts
    projectdicts = cloudresmanv1.projects().list().execute()
    projectdicts = projectdicts.get('projects')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

The above is taken from a Django form called ProjectForm.
However, after I've created a GCP project and browse within my Django app to the ProjectForm page again, the list doesn't update to show the newly-created project. My understanding is that it *should* run the above again, regardless.

If I run through the script manually, the *projectdicts* variable of course updates. So, this leads me to believe for some reason the Django app or Python is caching the variable and not bothering to run the above again.

Is this a likely problem? And if so, how do I force Django/Python to re-run this part of the script again to ensure the list of GCP projects is updated whenever I browse to the ProjectForm page?

**Edit 09/09/2020:**
Here's the full form, as requested in the comments:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    client = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Client Name (lowercase)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-z]+$', 'Enter a valid client name (only lowercase letters)')])
    stage = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)
    folder = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FOLDERS, required=False, label='')
    purpose = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Project Purpose (lowercase; digit optional)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-z-]+[1-9]?$', 'Enter a valid purpose (only lowercase letters, with a single optional digit)')])
    computeapi = forms.BooleanField(required=True, initial=True, label='Compute Engine')
    deploymentmanapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Deployment Manager')
    storagecompapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Storage Components')
    monitorapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Monitoring')
    loggingapi = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Logging')

    def clean(self):
        form_data = super(ProjectForm, self).clean()
        projectname = form_data['client'] + "-" + form_data['stage'] + "-" + form_data['purpose']
        client = form_data['client']
        purpose = form_data['purpose']
        for projectdict in projectdicts:
            if projectname == projectdict['name']:
                raise ValidationError(projectname + " already exists! Please try another name.")
        
        if not re.match("^[a-z-]+[1-9]?$", purpose):
            raise ValidationError(purpose + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
        
        if not re.match("^[a-z]+$", client):
            raise ValidationError(client + " does not comply with the Regex parameters.")
        return form_data
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Button('back', 'Back', css_class='button button--wide button--black', onclick="window.location.href = '{}';".format(reverse('home'))))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('next', 'Next', css_class='button button--wide button--white'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Project Name',
                Row(
                    Column('client', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                    Column('stage', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                    Column('purpose', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                )
            ),
            Fieldset(
                'Folder Name',
                Row(
                    Column('folder', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0')
                )
            ),
            Fieldset(
                'APIs To Enable',
                Row(
                    Column('computeapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0'),
                    Column('deploymentmanapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0'),
                    Column('storagecompapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0'),
                    Column('monitorapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0'),
                    Column('loggingapi', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0')
                )
            ),
        )
```

Comment: probably `global projectdicts` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why a global variable caches and doesn't update? Sorry, I'm new to this and using a global variable, though arguably counter-intuitive, was the only way I could use it in a new class when cleaning the form data.

Comment: Can you share the form, please? Or at least showcase where is the variable declared and used.

Comment: Sure - that's now been updated.